# HttpMessageNotReadableException instead of BeanPropertyBindingResult

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a form with a Double field. When I add a value which is not a Double ('foo') it should give me a `BeanPropertyBindingResult` with an error for that field. But instead i get a `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.

The strange thing is that from my JUnit test I do get the `BeanPropertyBindingResult`

Here is my code (i try to focus on what I think is needed if more is needed I will provide it).

I have an Angular frontend:

First here is the error i get from Angular:

> 2018-05-22 11:28:59.143  WARN 1262 --- [  XNIO-8 task-4]
>   o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Bad Request: JSON parse
>   error: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Double from String
>   "dddddddd": not a valid Double value; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   deserialize value of type java.lang.Double from String "dddddddd": not
>   a valid Double value  at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@36d5105f; line: 1, column: 1294] (through
>   reference chain: nl.tibi.sbys.service.dto.ProjectDTO["travelRate"])
>   2018-05-22 11:28:59.146  WARN 1262 --- [  XNIO-8 task-4]
>   .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by  Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Double
>   from String "dddddddd": not a valid Double value; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   deserialize value of type java.lang.Double from String "dddddddd": not
>   a valid Double value at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@36d5105f;
>   line: 1, column: 1294] (through reference chain:
>   nl.tibi.sbys.service.dto.ProjectDTO["travelRate"])

when i run the code from my junit test i get this, which is what i think is best:

> 2018-05-22 11:32:00.516  WARN 18426 --- [           main]
>   o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Bad Request:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'projectDTO' on field 'travelRate': rejected
>   value [3,5]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.projectDTO.travelRate,typeMismatch.travelRate,typeMismatch.java.lang.Double,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [projectDTO.travelRate,travelRate]; arguments []; default
>   message [travelRate]]; default message [Failed to convert property
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Double'
>   for property 'travelRate'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3,5"]

My angular code sends like this:

```
update( project: Project ): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    const copy = this.convert( project );
    return this.http.put<Project>( this.resourceUrl, copy, { observe: 'response' } )
        .map(( res: EntityResponseType ) => this.convertResponse( res ) );
}
```

my junit test is this:

```
restMockMvc.perform(post(url()).param("travelRate", "3,5").param("name", "name")).andExpect(status().isUnprocessableEntity());
```

My method (which is not reached because of the wrong decimal value):

```
   @PostMapping()
   @Timed
   public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> createProject(@Valid ProjectDTO projectDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to save Project : {}", projectDTO);
    ....
    }
```

How can I get the same result from Angular as from my JUnit test? ie how do I get a BeanPropertyBindingResult?

my workaround can be adding an ExceptionHandler and parsing the string message and create the BeanPropertyBindingResult myself

Answer (score 1):

The message is clear: Cannot convert a string parameter to your `Double` property.

The request body reader happens before your bean validation logic so `BeanPropertyBindingResult` exception does not occur.

If you want to verify input was correctly a double, you have to declare it as `String` in your DTO and valid it using custom validator:

```
public class ProjectDTO {
    @Double
    String travelRate;
}
```

Here `@Double` is your custom validator. Which is easily implemented.

Comment: Because you did not set a json converter for MockMvc yet

Comment: interesting, could you explain?

Comment: Add a jackson converter as your message converter and you"ll know why

Comment: do you have an example? So what you are saying that it is not possible to let spring boot give back a binding result instead of a HttpMessageNotReadableException after wrong input?